# Set up Android testing in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea

Have someone got any tutorials for how to do testing on Android in Intellij? I am looking for  resources similar to what you find for Eclipse with the ability to create a test project for my android project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some help in the [IDEA forum thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5254956).

Tests for Android application should be located in a separate module with its
own **AndroidManifest.xml** file. To find out how to create tests for your
Android application, you can use samples in Android SDK (i.e. "Snake"
sample).

Create IDEA project from existing sources. 2 modules with
Android facets will be created automatically: base module and "tests". Then
add dependency between these module and compile. If compilation is
successful, open some test class (i.e. "SkeletonAppTest" in "Snake" sample)
in editor and select **Run->SkeletonAppTest** (with Android icon) in the popup
menu: tests will run on emulator or device. You can create **Android
Tests** run configuration to run tests in different scopes.

Unfortunately, IDEA 9 doesn't have an option to create test module for some
base Android module. You can create it using [SDK command-line tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html).

Comment: There is also a blog post explaining how it works in IDEA 10: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/android-unit-testing-support/

Answer (score -1):

Here's the general Android/Eclipse info:

Android testing overview:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html

Testing practicalities for Eclipse and command line:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/index.html

Tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html

and to create a test project in IntelliJ:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/android-unit-testing-support/